# backpropagation; differentiation w.r.t bias

Tags: backpropagation

Probable, it is a silly question, but I cannot handle it at the moment.

Given:

[image]

input: 3

hidden1: 4

hidden2: 4

output: 2

[image]

Output layer does not have any activation function. My question is, how do I apply the chain rule for b3 (bias 3). Regarding my calculation I get following multiplication:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "derivative" $\frac{\partial error}{\partial b_3}$ is actually the gradient $\nabla_{b_3}error$, so you need to use the [chain rule for gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Chain_rule) here:
$$\nabla_{b_3}error = J_{b_3}output^T \nabla_{output} error.$$
Indeed, $$\nabla_{output} error = f(x)-y,$$ but
$$J_{b_3}output = \begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\ 0& 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence, 
$$\nabla_{b_3}error = f(x)-y.$$

Comment: thank you for your answer! 

 $$J_{b_3}output = \begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\ 0& 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

why it is a eigenvalue matrix?

Comment: $$\\
f(x)= x
\\
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = 1 
$$

I suppose because of the same logic as written above?

unfortunately, I am not confident in derivation in vector space

I would be very glad if you could advice me a good literature regarding this topic

Comment: Absolutely correct, just the "eigenvalue matrix" is called "identity matrix".